# Reference contract own address in vyper

Tags: vyper

how do you reference your own contract address in vyper, for example in solidity you would do something like that:

```
address(this)
```

Is there a way to do the same in vyper? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vyper equivalent to Solidity's `address(this)` is `self`.  You can verify it with this simple contract:

```py
@public
@constant
def foo() -> address:
    return self
```

Comment: In general, if you've got a question on Vyper syntax, worth looking here: https://reference.auditless.com/cheatsheet/.